# C# performing bitwise operation with & from C++

Tags: c#, c++, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

Anyway here's my problem I have been modifying a whole C++ program to work in C# and I am pretty much done, I have this If statement in the C++ program.

```
if(info[i].location & 0x8 || 
             info[i].location & 0x100|| 
                     info[i].location & 0x200)
{
    //do work
}
else
{
    return
}
```

And of course when I do this in C# it gives me a "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'" error.

Any clue on what my problem is, Im guessing that C# has got a way of doing this as I am fairly unfamiliar with these old C operators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Why it fails**

Fundamentally it's the same difference as this:

```
if (someInteger) // C or C++
```

vs

```
if (someInteger != 0) // C#
```

Basically C# is a lot stricter when it comes to logical operators and conditions - it forces you to have use something which is either `bool` or convertible to `bool`.

As an aside, that's *also* why in C# this isn't just a warning, but a full-blown error:

```
int x = ...;
if (x = 10) // Whoops - meant to be == but it's actually an assignment
```

If you see comparisons this way round:

```
if (10 == x)
```

That's *usually* developers trying to avoid typos like the above - but it's not needed in C# unless you're *really* comparing against constant `bool` values.

**Fixing the problem**

I suspect you just need:

```
if (((info[i].location & 0x8) != 0)) ||
    ((info[i].location & 0x100) != 0)) ||
    ((info[i].location & 0x200) != 0)))
```

It's possible that you don't need *all* of those brackets... but another alternative is just to use *one* test:

```
if ((info[i].location & 0x308) != 0)
```

After all, you're just testing whether any of those three bits are set...

You should also consider using a flags-based enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum LocationTypes
{
    Foo = 1 << 3; // The original 0x8
    Bar = 1 << 8; // The original 0x100
    Baz = 1 << 9; // The original 0x200
}
```

Then you could use:

```
LocationTypes mask = LocationTypes.Foo | LocationTypes.Bar | LocationTypes.Baz;
if ((info[i].location) & mask != 0)
```

Or using [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com):

```
LocationTypes mask = LocationTypes.Foo | LocationTypes.Bar | LocationTypes.Baz;
if (info[i].location.HasAny(mask))
```

Comment: Or even better--define each bit as a constant and bitwise-or them together into a mask to compare against

Comment: @DougT.: That's pretty much what my last edit was about - but instead of several integer constants, use an enum.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty much exactly what it says: in C#, `||` is a logical-only operator and so cannot work on `int`.  You can replace `||` with `|`  (the bitwise-or which works on `ints`), but then the entire expression will need to be converted to boolean by comparing it to zero, because in C# the `if`-statements require a boolean.

Alternatively, you can replace `info[i].location & 0x8` with `(info[i].location & 0x8 != 0)`.

Comment: +1, better answer because it explains why the compiler is giving an error.

Comment: Jon Skeet was just way faster